# Angularjs Popover shows arrow on button click for the very first time

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

On-click of button, a popover appears but an arrow appears for few seconds and then popover displays. This happens for the very first time when I clicked on button to display popover. After first popover is loaded, no arrow appears for further clicks.

If I refresh page and click button(to display popover) again, the arrow appears for few seconds and then it displays the popover.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I have the same issue with timepickers, you should first try ng-cloak.

http://www.w3schools.com/angular/ng_ng-cloak.asp

The thing is that angular takes time to load the tamplate and shows raw material. That's why it appears only the first time, because after that it is loaded and cashed.

You can try to load the template when the controller loads. Check your console to see what is loaded when you click the button so that you know what to call.

I also tried ng-include to load my popup template before the button was pressed. Not perfect but got things a bit better.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: ng-cloak not worked for me.can i use $templateCache for this problem. $templateCache.put('templateId.html', 'This is the content of the template');

Comment: also something like $http.get('templateId.html', { cache: $templateCache }); inside the controller can do the work.